# Установка php ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, php7

Как установить php 7.2(или 7.1) со всеми необходимыми модулями на вдс(ubuntu)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/856793/upgrade-to-the-specific-php-7-1-from-php-7-0-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Блин ты издиваешся? - на это милиард статей написно. И что ты подразумеваешь под "необходимыми модулями" ?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вам ознакомиться с [данной](http://help.ubuntu.ru/fullcircle/31/server_%D1%87_1) статьёй

Ранее она очень помогла мне в поднятии своего тестового сервера.

Если нужно просто поставить php

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1
```